# How should I troubleshoot a non-responsive datalab?

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

My notebooks often become non-responsive while using a datalab VM hosted on Google Cloud Compute Engine.  All of the open tabs I have in Chrome (project file directory, a couple of notebooks, and Ungit) will not reload.  If I let it wait several minutes the tabs will recover, but then shortly after they will go back to being unresponsive.  Currently, the only workaround I have is to reset the VM, which seems to correct the problem for a little while (less than an hour).  I have checked the VM monitoring and I do not see any resource exhaustion, the CPU never exceeds 50%.  The logs do not contain any warnings or errors.  How should I proceed with troubleshooting a non-responsive datalab?

Comment: I created a new datalab VM and it has been stable.  I would still like to know how to determine what is wrong with my other datalab.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding how to diagnose it, you can try the following:

1. Run `!ps auxfww` inside of a code cell. That will tell you which processes are running, and you can see if there is something running that shouldn't be.
2. Run `!top -b -n 1` inside of a code cell to see what processes are using which resources. That can tell you if there is something using a lot of RAM or CPU.
3. Run `!df -h` inside of a code cell to see how much disk space you have available. If one of the disk partitions fills up then that may cause issues.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to [update the Datalab instance](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/lifecycle#updating_the_cloud_datalab_vm_without_deleting_the_notebooks_disk), to do so you will have to delete the instance while keeping the disk. Once that is done you can create it using the same disk:

```
datalab delete --keep-disk instance-name
datalab create instance-name
```

By doing this you are creating the instance with the latest update which have the issues fixed.